# Tiles jsp page with other URL content

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tiles

I am working in Spring MVC project.For UI, I am using tiles framework.

Everything is going well till I am accessing all my jsp files.

Now I want to show a google webpage inside my bodyand keep header and footer as common.

I am using the following code to get but not able to get the google url in body tag. it shows the url text in that body.

```
<definition name="losmain" extends="baseLayout">

    <put-attribute name="title" value="title" />

    <put-attribute name="import"

        value="/views/los/dashboard_import.jsp" />

    <put-attribute name="body" value="http://google.co.in" />

</definition>
```

can anyone suggest a right way to get google url in body.

Comment: tiles nor jstl can import the content of a different url resource for you. you need to download that other webpage using something like apache's httpclient or a URLConnection.

Comment: Is it possible to send a text box value from existing webpage to that URL and get the response to existing webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of Google is restricting on loading its URL from third party's IP address.